# I Want to Get Total Number of days in every month in a current year. what function I have to use in php

Tags: php, date

```
 I tried this:
    $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,4,2016);
    echo $d;
    $d gives=>30
```

Which is current  day for this month and year for 2016. Here I have given month and year manually. How do I bring automatically for every year.Is there any function like this. my objective is I want to know how many days in a month.

Comment: Put it in a loop, incrementing from 1 to 12

Comment: For year you want to use: `date("Y")` and for month: `date("m")`

Comment: By making a for loop : `for ($y = 1980; $y <= 2016; $y++) {for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $y); ...}}`

Comment: Mark. I am stuck with loop. could you please help, I tried at my end . no answer

Comment: Thanks for your input,chuck I tested in server it shows 31 for this month. help me please,month is not reflecting properly

Comment: Chuck Norris any help, I am trying on that only. it shows again 31 for this month. if I change $m to 4 it gives 30.

Comment: [Demo of @ChuckNorris code](https://3v4l.org/sTLIu)

Comment: ok. But  expected result I got  it,This is the answer I am looking for. I have change this line  $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $y)  to$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), $y); Thanks for Chuck NOrris. how do I tick the answer?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for($i=1;$i<= 12;$i++)
{
 $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$i ,2016);

echo $i.' -> '.$d;
}
```

It should work .

Comment: I have tested it is not coming. check at ur end. it show like this at my end:1 -> 312 -> 293 -> 314 -> 305 -> 316 -> 307 -> 318 -> 319 -> 3010 -> 3111 -> 3012 -> 31

Comment: Place echo '<br/>'; after echo $i.' -> '.$d;

Comment: It is working. actually days number and count echoed side by side .That is why you see 312,  293 and so on.It means 1 refers to january=> 31 ,febfruary=>29 and so on.

Comment: Hi done, but how do i increase for next year, now 2016 is static.

Comment: Ok. Just do another loop for year

Comment: hello I am asking you how to write that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109032/discussion-between-bikash-paul-and-web-resource).